# Margins for A4 with and without geometry package

Tags: margins

I am trying to figure out the margins of the document class article. I know this layout figure: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout

The article says that I can change the paper size to A4 by giving the option `a4paper` but it only comes to effect if I also use the geometry package, i.e.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
```

or

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
```

However, `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}` alone gives me another format than `letter` and also calling the geometry package changes the margins again.

Furthermore, in the `\layout` figure, I am wondering if there is the exact the same space on the left and on the right, same with top/bottom.

Is the `\layout` command the only way to see the values for the page margins or is it possible to directly return the values of left, right, top, bottom?

Comment: You should distinguish between the paper format (i.e. its physical dimensions) and the margins. While paper formats are following some (internationally known) standards, there are no such standards on the margins. `geometry` surely uses some default values for margins; Of course, `a4paper` will only work with `geometry`, since this package defines that option (at least this is only one I know of)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Isn't `a4paper` defined in all standard classes? Ok, it will only change the papersize and not the margins, but it is defined.

Comment: @samcarter: Of course, you're right, I forgot about those options.

Comment: I get an A4 document when I add the `a4paper` document class option, and a US letter otherwise *without* adding [`geometry`](//ctan.org/pkg/geometry). So you must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Changing the 2nd part of my comment above: standard documentclasses do provide `a4paper`, but `geometry` seems to change the margins as well

Comment: `geometry` seems to drastically change the margins while I actually thought it takes the default values if no arguments for margins are given. That is why I am so curious.

Comment: @00schneider `geometry` has its own set of default values, which it uses if no values are given. Without the `geometry` package only the paper size is changed. All other things, like the `\textwidth` will stay the same. With the geometry package, also things like `\textwidth` will be changed.

Comment: @00schneider: `geometry` uses defaults (via calculation etc.), see page 13 of the current `geometry` manual

Comment: You can use the `layouts` package (`> texdoc layouts`) to show many kinds of layouts, not just of the page,  and also you can try some experimental ones.

Comment: I’m sorry, but I cannot understand exactly what you are trying to achieve and where your actual problem lies.  By any chance, does loading the `geometry` package with the `pass` option (_i.e._, `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` help in any way?

Comment: Yeah, that does the trick. I was simply confused that geometry changes the margins without any arguments given. Nevermind...

Comment: @samcarter `a4paper` sets \textwidth` in the standard classes whether or not geometry is used

Comment: @DavidCarlisle however in the standard classes `\textwidth` will be set to the same value while geometry uses different values, correct?

Comment: @samcarter well try it with a5paper, , article class calculates textwidth depending on paperwidth so the calculation for usletter and a4paper are different, however it has a cutoff of 345pt, so  in fact the value of textwidth ends up being 345 for those two sizes (see size10.clo around line 105)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, you are of course right! I stopped testing after letter and a4 paper :)